# ¿Diferencia entre struct y vectores STL en C++?

Tags: c++, struct

Si tengo:

```
struct Film {
    string title;
    string director;
    int year;
};
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre usar vectores STL y struct?

Es decir, qué diferencia hay entre hacer vector<**Film**> Vfilms y hacer **Film** films?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Con `vector<Film> Vfilms` tienes un vector de objetos de la clase Film. Con `Film films` tienes un objeto de la clase Film.

Comment: ¿Hacen la misma función o cuáles son las utilidades diferentes?

Comment: Un objeto es eso un solo objeto y un vector es un contenedor en el que puedes meter tantos objetos como quieras y acceder a ellos uno a uno cuando los necesites. No son cosas comparables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Qué diferencia hay entre un escalón y una escalera?

[image]
[image]

---

¿Qué diferencia hay entre un eslabón y una cadena?

[image]
[image]

---

¿Qué diferencia hay entre una perla y un collar?

[image]
[image]

---

¿Qué diferencia hay entre un cartel y una cartelera?

> ¿Qué diferencia hay entre usar vectores STL y struct?

El primero es una colección de objetos, el segundo un objeto.

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!! Así me queda muchísimo más claro.

Comment: Una imagen vale más que mil palabras